# Email Count Based on Category

Tags: vba, count, outlook, categories

I am connected to my company's MS Exchange. From my own Outlook profile, I access a generic mailbox. All incoming messages will be tagged to a category and then moved to a folder (***Mailbox - Generic > Resolved***). How can I generate a total count of each category in this folder?

**Mailbox - Javen**

- Inbox
- Sent Items
- ...

**Mailbox - Generic**

- Inbox
- Sent Items
- Resolved
- ...

Each category will be named to a name...

Example: Red = John, Yellow = Peter, Purple = Peggy

Answer (score 2):

This should get you going. It filters the folder a specified category. You can edit it to do loop of the Outlook Categories collection to get the counts. Or you could change it to be a function that returns the count...passing the Category name as a parameter.

```
Private Sub CountbyCategory()
    Dim fldr As Outlook.Folder = Nothing
    Dim itms As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim filteredItms As Outlook.Items = Nothing


    'Do this for each category...
    Dim typeFilter As String = "[Category] = " & Chr(39) & "INSERT CATEGORY NAME HERE" & Chr(39)

    'This assumes default inbox, you'll need to select you folder...maybe use PickFolder?
    'fldr = Application.Session.PickFolder()
    fldr = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    itms = fldr.Items
    filteredItms = itms.Restrict(typeFilter)

    Dim iCount As Integer = filteredItms.Count

    'Repeat for each category
End Sub
```

You can learn more about working with Outlook items here:
[Working with Outlook mail items: how to create, delete, access & enumerate](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/06/03/outlook-mail-items-create-delete-access/)

[Working with Outlook Accounts, Stores, Folders and Items](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/05/31/outlook-accounts-stores-folders-items/)

Comment: For me it needed to be [Categories] instead, great answer never the less